# Distinct st_shortestline

Tags: postgis, nearest-neighbor, knn

I have 61 pts and numerous rds. I would like to find the shortest distance to the nearest road using st_shortestline. I need 61 unique line segments, one for each point to its nearest road. Instead I am getting 61 line segments from each point to a particular road (not the nearest). How can I adjust my query to produce the proper results?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id) p.id, p._unique, r.rd_name, ST_ShortestLine(p.geom,r.geom) into shortest_line FROM pois_sample p, allrds_sample r;
```

Outcome:

[image]

Desired Outcome:

[image]

Comment: you are looking for a *(K) Nearest Neighbor* search, see e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287810/93656) for a comprehensive `SELECT` example, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279397/93656) for a generic `UPDATE` syntax, and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278362/93656) for more on both. - all my own answers, there's plenty more on *(K)NN* searches on GIS.SE

Comment: This does not utilize st_shortest line. Is this not the exact use case for [st_shortestline](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ShortestLine.html)?

Comment: yes and no; `ST_ShortesLine` does give you what it says, the issue is the cross join of your tables; for each point, this will create the shorest line from it *to every road*! if you want the shortest line to the *one closest road* for each point, a `LATERAL JOIN` is needed. to speed things up, PostGIS offers the *KNN* operator `<->` (see links). if you then also only want the *(numerical) distance*, use e.g. `ST_Distance` (or replace it with `ST_ShortestLine` otherwise). if you have trouble translating it to your usecase, I write up an answer. this is, however, a close duplicate to the links.

Comment: Thanks @thingumabob. I can see the similarities.  What I need in the end is the line geometry (as returned with st_shortestline) and not point geometry returned. Can you provide an example which does this? These examples look complex and I'm having trouble following.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE shortest_line AS
  SELECT p.id,
         p._unique,
         r.rd_name
         ST_ShortestLine(p.geom, r.geom)::GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, <your_epsg>) AS geom
  FROM  pois_sample AS p
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT rd_name,
           geom
    FROM   allrds_sample
    ORDER BY
           geom <-> p.geom
    LIMIT  1
  ) AS r
;
```

**Make sure you have spatial indexes in place**, at least on the `allrds_sample` table, for this to be highly performant.

The explicit cast to `GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, <your_epsg>)` will ensure the `shortest_line.geom` column will be correctly registered in PostGIS' `geometry_colums`table.

---

The core concept is the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`:

- `pois_sample` will be traversed sequentially and each row passed (made available) to
  the right hand query of the join as reference
- in that sub-query, the geometries from `allrds_sample` will get ordered by distance to the geometry passed in from the outer row, using the special *(K)NN* distance operator `<->`
- the default ascending order plus the `LIMIT 1` makes sure we get only the closest geometry to the reference geometry
- the `JOIN` itself then makes all returned rows in `allrds_sample` available to the left hand (outer) `SELECT`

In other words:

- *for each geometry in `pois_sample`, scan `allrds_sample` for the nearest and return it*

where the time consuming operation that one might expect here is highly optimized by the `<->` operator in the `ORDER BY`, in conjunction with a spatial index.

Comment: Thank you @thingumabob. This did exactly what I needed it to.