# Splitting Lines with Points using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, splitting

I have a line table and a points table in PostGIS. I need to split the line table with the points table and return all geometries.

I tried using:

```
CREATE TABLE lines_split AS (
SELECT
a.seg_name, ((ST_DUMP(ST_SPLIT(a.geom,b.geom))).geom) as geom
FROM lines_table a
INNER JOIN points_table b
ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geom, b.geom)
);
```

This runs successfully with unusual results. It returns a subset (pink lines) of the lines which are not split by the points.

[image: unusual subset results]

I have this now:

[image: I have this now]

I want this:

[image: I want this]

How do I perform this task in PostGIS?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112282/split-lines-into-non-overlapping-subsets-based-on-points (cannot vote to close bountied questions)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have tried every other related post to accomplish this simple task and nothing has worked. Ive offered a bounty for this task. If you have knowledge here please divulge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The core issue with your query is that you split every line by every point *individually*, as a result of the table join; if one line is to be split by two points, **that same original line will be split once for each point** instead of twice!

Also, you need to explicitly select those geometries that are not split; I just updated the queries to include them.

You need to split each line by *all* points:

```
WITH
  blade AS (
    SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom
    FROM   points_table
  )

SELECT a.seg_name,
       dmp.geom
FROM   lines_table AS a,
       blade AS b,
       LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_Split(a.geom, b.geom)) AS dmp
UNION ALL
SELECT seg_name,
       geom
FROM   lines_table AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   points_table AS b
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
);
```

or, for a large amount of points as blade:

```
SELECT seg_name,
       (ST_Dump(ST_Split(
         a.geom,
         (SELECT ST_Collect(b.geom) AS geom FROM points_table AS b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
       )).geom
FROM   lines_table AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT seg_name,
       geom
FROM   lines_table AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   points_table AS b
  WHERE  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
);
```

---

A core issue with your data may be that, if your points are not directly derived off the lines, the chance that they don't match is very high (PostGIS stores up to 15 decimal places of coordinate precision...plenty of room for mismatches)!

If some of your lines are not split at all, you have to make the points snap to the lines. Two ways of doing this:

- use `ST_Snap` with a tiny tolerance to match each segment **to the
  blade** (snapping the blade to the segments would result in *one*
  point of the blade being snapped to the segment only), which results
  in slightly misplaces split lines
- update the `points_table` with the the `ST_ClosestPoint` within a *Nearest Neighbor* search (see e.g. my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279387/automatically-snapping-points-to-closest-part-of-line/279397#279397)); that way you guarantee that points will be snapped to their nearest segment. This *might* lead to mismatched points in edge cases (a point close to two segments e.g. at an intersection, might lead to that point being located on the wrong segment)

Comment: The second version (for a large amount of points as blade) doesn't seem to work for me.  It just returns the original table + a few more more lines.  I created the points via LineInterpolatePoint, so they should intersect with the line.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I have also snapped all the points to the line in an effort to ensure everything is lined up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of geozelot helped me on my way to a solution.
I created a view with points derived with ST_LineInterpolatePoint out of a LRS table and used it so split the lines of the base table for dynamic segmentation in another view. Micro gaps between the point and the line vetcors require ST_Snap.
I want to post this here just in case someone also needs this:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS gid,
    _subq_1_.rid,
    _subq_1_.geom

FROM ( WITH pc AS (
              SELECT st_collect(pointtable.geom) AS geom
              FROM pointtable
              WHERE *FilterPointsIfNeeded*
              )
         SELECT a.seg_name AS rid,
            (st_dump(st_split(st_snap(a.geom, pc.geom, 0.0000001), pc.geom))).geom AS geom
           FROM linetable a,
            pc) _subq_1_;
```